# Jooq record.into(Pojo.class) with same fields name problem

Tags: java, sql, mapping, pojo, jooq

I have code that retrieves one record of 2 objects(POJO generated by JooQ) from 2 tables.

```
 Record record = dsl.select()
            .from(ISSUE)
            .leftJoin(CLIENT).on(CLIENT.ID.eq(ISSUE.CLIENT_ID))
            .where(ISSUE.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOne();
    JIssue jIssue = record.into(JIssue.class);
    JClientRecord jClient = record.into(JClientRecord.class);
```

Both table ISSUE and table CLIENT have PK field "ID".

The problem is when mapping into(POJO.class), table fields that have same names not mapped correctly to POJO.
In example above **jIssue takes id of jClient**.

When using TableRecords instead of POJO's all mapping done correctly, but you cant use TableRecord in generated DAO, it takes generated POJO.

How can i solve this problem so jooq could map to generated pojo fields correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The POJO classes do not have any reliable meta information to clearly disambiguate between two equally named columns from the source record. However, you can copy your joined record into a `TableRecord` for each table, and then copy that record again into your POJO:

```
JIssue jIssue = record.into(ISSUE).into(JIssue.class);
JClientRecord jClient = record.into(CLIENT).into(JClientRecord.class);
```